# How might I log my Internet traffic, grouped by IP address/hostname, port, etc?

Tags: networking, monitoring, bandwidth, packet

While I'm going to be switching to a slightly saner plan soon, being stuck on a 5GB monthly bandwidth cap has made me very data-conscious, and I'm looking for a way to log my Internet usage in such a way that I can see how much I've uploaded, and how much I've downloaded, to each port on each host/IP I visit; seeing "you downloaded 823.64MB and uploaded 92.12MB last Tuesday" on my ISP's web portal isn't *especially* insightful...

I have a couple of extra considerations I'd like to take into account:

- I would like the monitoring system to be as lightweight as possible. While existing software would be preferred, at the most extreme I'd consider a simple homemade C libpcap program, if there are examples that I could get up and running from with less than 150 lines of trivial modifications.
- Since just about everything that works with a domain name is going to do a DNS lookup to find the IP address, a system which sniffs for the DNS lookup response and uses that to associate IP addresses with hostnames - rather than making an indepentant/spurious call - would be nice to have.

Answer (score 0):

- [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) have a great community around. There must be a solution.

  For example: Raw dumping full of traffic via tcpdump, as you are mention, there is not so much - 5GB. With 8GB or 16GB of RAM you could read this file on the PC in probably maximally optimal format today with wireshark.

  In this case CPU load a bit.
- Have you look at the [ntop](http://www.ntop.org/)?

  Since they are going deep, there is no mysql support anymore. Somehow, part of IP addresses truncated from time to time. I can't guarantee that this tool will logs everything.

  Sometimes, it takes a huge part of CPU.
- Look at [splunk](http://www.splunk.com) - it is commercial product with demo period.

  There are so many beautiful plugins! Not leave indifferent anybody.

All this three tools can give you logging by ip:port.

Comment: I frequently use Wireshark myself - used it earlier today to check a browser's POST output :) - but only to capture specific information. I'll see what the community says - I asked http://ask.wireshark.org/questions/30791/memorycpu-load-of-continuous-gui-less-background-bandwidth-usage-monitoring. What do you mean by "not so much - 5GB"? This PC has 640MB of RAM in it, and it also does many other tasks, so I really meant ***lightweight*** :P Thanks for the mention about ntop; won't go there ;) - and I've heard of Splunk, but I get the impression I'd need a datacenter to take advantage of it :P